# A way to share modules between python 3.4 installation standard and anaconda py34 one

Tags: python, module, anaconda

I'd like to use either python 3.4 installation standard and Anaconda with python 3.4 in the same Computer. But when I make a standard installation of a new module or python installation (for example pip install Django) all is right in anaconda environment but it doesn't work in the python 3.4 standard environment. My OS is Windows 7 and I'd like a solution not like sys.path.append() which I should execute everytime I start Python 3.4 standard version

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution or better I learn a thing I did not know. For installing a module in the python 3.4 installation I should use per specif pip3.4.exe file which is in the directory scripts in the python 3.4 installation and not the "general" pip.exe file which install all the modules in the python 3.4 anaconda installation, which is considered the default one.

Answer (score 0):

You can set both site-packages directories in the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, or write a  `pth` file (see https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html) that imports one into the other. Just a warning though that this can get messy fast.